# How many environment frames are created when you have a function call in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

As you know when there is a function call, Scheme creates a new location for each call, and places the function parameters into the locations. 
For example when you have

```
(define r 5)
(define a 3)
(define (f x) (* x r))
```

the [following locations model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUvpC.png) is created in background:

```
{E} (f a)
{E} (f 3)
{E1} (* x r)
Final: 15
```

My question is how many locations are created when you execute this code and how the location model looks like:

```
(define (f a)
  (define (g b) (* a b))
  (g (g (+ a 1))))

(f 3) -> 36
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the environment frames created are as follows:

- E0 (top-level; context = `(define (f a) ...)`): f = #<procedure>
- E1 (parent = E0; context = `(f 3)`): a = 3
- E2 (parent = E1; context = `(define (g b) ...)`): g = #<procedure>
- E3 (parent = E2; context = `(+ a 1)`): lhs = 3, rhs = 1
- E4 (parent = E2; context = inner `(g ...)`): b = 4
- E5 (parent = E4; context = `(* a b)`): lhs = 3, rhs = 4
- E6 (parent = E2; context = outer `(g ...)`): b = 12
- E7 (parent = E6; context = `(* a b)`): lhs = 3, rhs = 12